# Can fetch images with albums before Android Q, but not on Android Q

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-10.0

I tried other solutions on Stack Overflow, but they are not working with my problem. The below code is working perfectly before Android Q versions, but did not work with Android Q.

Here are the functions which are used to fetch albums and images.

First for fetching AlbumImages:

```
 public static ArrayList<ImageFolder> getPicturePaths(Context context){
    ArrayList<ImageFolder> picFolders = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> picPaths = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri allImagesuri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(allImagesuri, projection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            do {
                ImageFolder folds = new ImageFolder();
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String folder = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME));
                String datapath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));

                //String folderpaths =  datapath.replace(name,"");
                String folderpaths = datapath.substring(0, datapath.lastIndexOf(folder + "/"));
                folderpaths = folderpaths + folder + "/";
                if (!picPaths.contains(folderpaths)) {
                    picPaths.add(folderpaths);

                    folds.setPath(folderpaths);
                    folds.setFolderName(folder);
                    folds.setFirstPic(datapath);//if the folder has only one picture this line helps to set it as first so as to avoid blank image in itemview
                    folds.addpics();
                    picFolders.add(folds);
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < picFolders.size(); i++) {
                        if (picFolders.get(i).getPath().equals(folderpaths)) {
                            picFolders.get(i).setFirstPic(datapath);
                            picFolders.get(i).addpics();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return picFolders;
}
```

And here is the method to fetch images from albums:

```
    public static ArrayList<PhotoItemModel> getAllImagesByFolder(Context context, String path){
   ArrayList<PhotoItemModel> images = new ArrayList<>();
    Uri allImagesuri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA ,MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query( allImagesuri, projection, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[] {"%"+path+"%"}, null);
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                PhotoItemModel pic = new PhotoItemModel();

                pic.setPicturName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));

                pic.setPicturePath(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));

                pic.setPictureSize(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE)));

                images.add(pic);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
            ArrayList<PhotoItemModel> reSelection = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = images.size()-1;i > -1;i--){
                reSelection.add(images.get(i));
            }
            images = reSelection;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return images;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: In general, I recommend that questions do not pre-emptively ask for readers not to vote to close as a duplicate. Sure, it is good that you searched the site beforehand, but we want question authors to be open to the possibility that they missed one. Where a possible duplicate is proposed, we want question authors to be grateful that an answer might already exist, and we want authors to study how the proposed duplicate might fit their situation.

Comment: acknowledged  it

Comment: `but did not work `. Bad info. What exactly did go wrong?

Comment: @blackapps it did not show images in android q

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the Android Q is getting some problem (permission related) to reach Folder path

```
String folderpaths = datapath.substring(0, datapath.lastIndexOf(folder + "/"));
folderpaths = folderpaths + folder + "/";
```

Comment: Actually I have Android P, not having Android Q to test it where it is creating a problem. It is working on Genymotion emulator 10 but not on real device

Answer (score 0):

Under Android Q you cannot use the .DATA column.

Instead use .RELATIVE_PATH.

Read the threads tagged `mediastore`.

Comment: not working. Please answer with complete code for resolve issue